# Iterating over pairs of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, loops, coordinates, python-itertools, haversine

I have a list of coordinates:

```
[(52.472665, -1.8977818),
(52.47455886, -1.90080653),
(52.4515712, -1.9327772),
(52.45028622, -1.93212766),..]
```

I am trying to write code that will allow me to calculate the distance between each one using the Haversine module:

(pseudo code)

```
for points in daycoords1:

p1 = day1coords[0]

p2 = day1coords[1]

dist_miles = haversine(p1, p2, miles=True)

distday1.append(dist_miles)
```

Is there a way to pull in coordinates one and two, measure the distance, two and three and mesaure that distance etc.

I have been trying to use itertools and zip() but I am yet to have any luck.

Comment: I think you will have to use `for i in range(...)` instead of `for x in list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *exactly* sure what function you want to use from the `haversine` module, but to compare two consecutive items in your list of coordinates you can use a list comprehension with a `zip` of slices of your coordinates:

```
coords = [(52.472665, -1.8977818),
(52.47455886, -1.90080653),
(52.4515712, -1.9327772),
(52.45028622, -1.93212766)]

distances = [haversine(p1, p2, miles=True) for p1, p2 in zip(coords[:-1], coords[1:])]
```

This will compare `p1` to `p2`, `p2` to `p3`, `p3` to `p4` and so on....

Comment: there is no need to zip, you can just do:
for x,y in coords:
     etc

Comment: But then you won't be able to compare `x1, y1` with `x2, y2`

Comment: oh my bad, i thought he just want to unpack the coord itself not two at the time.

Comment: When using this the output of distance is still only giving that between the first two points?

Comment: Shouldn't do. Run `distances = [(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip(coords[:-1], coords[1:])]` to see the points you are comparing.

Comment: It's only incorporating two points, rather than the 10 that are within the list?

Comment: It compares point 1 to point 2, point 2 to point 3, etc. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: That is what I was hoping for but for some reason it only pulls in the first 2 points and then stops?

Comment: Double check your input. The code is correct

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is iterate over
 `zip(daycoords1, daycoords1[1:])` and do your calculations. Demo:

```
>>> daycoords1 = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> for x in zip(daycoords1, daycoords1[1:]):
...     print(x)
... 
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((3, 4), (5, 6))
```

If you have a lot of coordinates, consider `itertools.izip` for memory efficiency.

Comment: I like the fact that you don't need to slice the first `daycoords1` `zip` argument. Neat

Comment: @gtlambert yes `zip` will stop when the shortest iterable is exhausted. To go by the longest iterable, there's `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `range` as below if you want to calculate distance between two locations(one after another as shown in the `d` and looking forward).

```
from haversine import haversine

d = [(52.472665, -1.8977818),
(52.47455886, -1.90080653),
(52.4515712, -1.9327772),
(52.45028622, -1.93212766),(53.45028622, -1.93212766)]

data = []

for i in range(len(d)-1):
    data.append(haversine(d[i], d[i+1], miles=True))

print data
```

Output-

```
[0.18255943050822185, 2.0818287457607068, 0.09290096620460978, 69.0933027640562]
```

**EDIT**-
If you want to get distance between all the combinations( all possible non-duplicate pair of locations) in the `d` then -

```
from haversine import haversine
from itertools import combinations

d = [(52.472665, -1.8977818),
(52.47455886, -1.90080653),
(52.4515712, -1.9327772),
(52.45028622, -1.93212766),(52.45028622, -1.93212766)]

data = []

for pair in combinations(d,2):
    data.append(haversine(pair[0], pair[1], miles=True))

print data
```

Output-

```
[0.18255943050822185, 2.072320708393457, 2.1169388238266245, 2.1169388238266245, 2.0818287457607068, 2.1333352954019116, 2.1333352954019116, 0.09290096620460978, 0.09290096620460978, 0.0]
```

Comment: Does this not fail if their is an odd number of coordinates? Also this only allows p1 to be compared to p2, p3 to p4 etc...

Comment: Rather than all combinations I'm trying to get it to get the distance between p1 and p2, then p2 and p3, then p3 and p4, etc.

Comment: OK see modified answer..